# Cursor - Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, cursor, contactscontract

I rarely get following error:

```
Couldn't read row 439, col 60 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1433)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.getWindow(BulkCursorNative.java:164)
        at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.onMove(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:83)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:214)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:245)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToNext(CursorWrapper.java:166)
        at ....UpdatePhoneContactsJob.h(UpdatePhoneContactsJob.java:64)
```

The error line corresponds to `while (cursor.moveToNext())`... I use following function:

```
Cursor cursor = MainApp.get().getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,//ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
            null,
            null,//Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
            null,
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");

    int rawId = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
    int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
    int lookupKey = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY);
    // int photoUri = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_URI);
    int photoId = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_ID);
    int name = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int accountType = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.ACCOUNT_TYPE_AND_DATA_SET);
    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    int numberType = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
    int numberLabel = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL);
    int mimeType = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE);
    int rawContactName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME);

    ContactComparator compId = new ContactComparator(ContactComparator.Type.ID);
    ContactComparator compName = new ContactComparator(ContactComparator.Type.Name);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int phId = cursor.getInt(id);
        String phLookupKey = cursor.getString(lookupKey);
        // String phPhotoUri = cursor.getString(photoUri);
        int phPhotoId = cursor.getInt(photoId);
        long phRawId = cursor.getLong(rawId);
        String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
        int phNumberType = cursor.getInt(numberType);
        String phNumberLabel = cursor.getString(numberLabel);
        String phMimeType = cursor.getString(mimeType);
        String phAccountType = cursor.getString(accountType);
        String phRawContactName = cursor.getString(rawContactName);

        PhoneContact contact = new PhoneContact(phId, phRawId, phLookupKey, phPhotoId > 0);
        // funktioniert, weil Kontakte nach ID sortiert sind!
        int contactIndex = Collections.binarySearch(contacts, contact, compId);
        if (contactIndex < 0)
        {
            String phName = cursor.getString(name);
            contact.setName(phName);
            contacts.add(contact);
        }
        else
        {
            contact = contacts.get(contactIndex);
        }

        String accountName = BaseDef.makeAccountTypeReadable(phAccountType, phRawContactName);
        contact.addAccountType(accountName);

        // Liste der AccountTypen merken
        if (!accountTypes.contains(accountName))
            accountTypes.add(accountName);

        if (phMimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
        {
            String phoneLabel = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(MainApp.get().getResources(), phNumberType, phNumberLabel);
            contact.addNumber(phoneLabel, phNumber);
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
```

**Is this function prone to errors? What could I change to avoid the error mentioned above?**

Comment: Is it possible you are running into the size limit for Android Cursors (1MB)? 439 rows isn't a lot, but 60 columns is. The `Data.CONTENT_URI` performs joins on a couple of tables, and you may be including columns that you aren't interested in but which have a lot of data. Try specifying only the columns you actually need for the query instead of passing `null` (which selects all the columns).

Comment: I'll try that... though, this should happen on more devices then, shouldn't it? I saw logs of people with a few thousand contacts and it did not fail... Still, it of course makes sense to limit the cols to limit the error down

Comment: It might depend on what contact data is on that particular device. You might try adding the same google account on another device that has been factory reset, let the contacts sync, and see if it happens there too. I suppose also the OEM could change the maximum size of the Cursor if they wanted to...

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll limit the columns and try that...

Comment: I still get this error (with small col number and higher row number) ....Anything else I can do? Does it make any difference if I split the query into parts of 1000 rows and work with limit and offset? Or won't this change anything?

Comment: It might, you can give it a try